# Same frame multiple times when using select and vframes

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg in python using the ffmpeg-python wrapper

I run the following:

```
filename = "something.mp4"
frame_number = 5 # It works fine if I ask to start at 0

out, err = (
    ffmpeg.input(filename)
    .filter_('fps', fps=10)
    .filter_('select', 'gte(n,{})'.format(frame_number))
    .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt=no,uint32, vframes=5)
    .run(capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)
)
print(out)
# Then I parse it into numpy array
```

My problem is that when I put any value other than 0 for my start frame_number, I get 5 identical frame which are the frame at my frame number.

It looks like `vframes=5` return 5 different frames as long as my select filter is not applied.

But as soon as we select frames >= N, then it returns that Nth frame 5 times

What I have done wrong ?
How should I do what I'm trying to do ?

EDIT:

To help visualize what I mean here are a few examples:

frame_number = 0, vframes=5: `[0,1,2,3,4]` GOOD

frame_number = 5, vframes=1: `[5]` GOOD

frame_number = 5, vframes=5: `[5,5,5,5,5]` BAD, expected: `[5,6,7,8,9]`

Comment: After select, add this filter `setpts=PTS-STARTPTS` and check.

Comment: Thank you, this solve my issue, I don't quite understand why though. If you feel like making an answer with explanation I'd be more than happy to upvote and accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that you're selecting frames from inside the stream, which will typically star with a non-zero timestamp, and then outputting these frames via the rawvideo muxer. The rawvideo muxer is configured as a constant frame rate muxer, and ffmpeg will thus pad the output stream to start from timestamp 0 by cloning the first supplied frame.

One way of avoiding the cloning is by resetting the timestamps to start with 0 by inserting `setpts=PTS-STARTPTS` filter after `select`.